# Server Response (JSON Format) to Array Conversion

Tags: java, android, json, achartengine

I am working on an android app in which i send an http response to a server and get a response in string which is in JSON format, now on the basis of this response i need to generate a stacked column chart using AChartEngine for different equipments. The response string looks like as follows

```
[{"ChartDate":null,"CycleStatus":null,"Cycle_Duration":0,"Cycle_Percent":0,"Duration":0,"EquipmentDescription":"MTConnect","EquipmentId":5,"EquipmentName":"MTC 1","EquipmentStatusColor":null,"EquipmentStatusDescription":null,"EquipmentStatusId":0,"EquipmentStatusIdentifier":null,"EquipmentStatusTypeId":0,"EquipmentStatusTypeName":null,"EquipmentStatusTypeName_resourceKey":null,"EquipmentTimeZoneId":null,"EventData":null,"GeneralStatusState":0,"IsFirstRowData":false,"Percentage":0,"ReportGroupId":0,"ReportGroupName":null,"ReportGroupValue":null,"StatusAction":0,"StatusDuration":[{"ChartDate":null,"CycleStatus":null,"Cycle_Duration":0,"Cycle_Percent":0,"Duration":561.60722222222023,"EquipmentDescription":"MTConnect","EquipmentId":5,"EquipmentName":"MTC 1","EquipmentStatusColor":"#008000","EquipmentStatusDescription":"In Cycle","EquipmentStatusId":0,"EquipmentStatusIdentifier":null,"EquipmentStatusTypeId":1,"EquipmentStatusTypeName":null,"EquipmentStatusTypeName_resourceKey":"EquipmentStatusTypeName.InCycle","EquipmentTimeZoneId":null,"EventData":null,"GeneralStatusState":0,"IsFirstRowData":false,"Percentage":0,"ReportGroupId":0,"ReportGroupName":null,"ReportGroupValue":null,"StatusAction":0,"StatusDuration":null,"TimeStamp":{"DateTime":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","OffsetMinutes":0},"UnknownDowntime_Duration":0,"UnknownDowntime_Percent":0},{"ChartDate":null,"CycleStatus":null,"Cycle_Duration":0,"Cycle_Percent":0,"Duration":134.57583333333525,"EquipmentDescription":"MTConnect","EquipmentId":5,"EquipmentName":"MTC 1","EquipmentStatusColor":"#FFFF00","EquipmentStatusDescription":"In Cycle","EquipmentStatusId":0,"EquipmentStatusIdentifier":"","EquipmentStatusTypeId":2,"EquipmentStatusTypeName":null,"EquipmentStatusTypeName_resourceKey":"EquipmentStatusTypeName.UnknownDowntime","EquipmentTimeZoneId":null,"EventData":null,"GeneralStatusState":0,"IsFirstRowData":false,"Percentage":0,"ReportGroupId":0,"ReportGroupName":null,"ReportGroupValue":null,"StatusAction":0,"StatusDuration":null,"TimeStamp":{"DateTime":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","OffsetMinutes":0},"UnknownDowntime_Duration":0,"UnknownDowntime_Percent":0}],"TimeStamp":{"DateTime":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","OffsetMinutes":0},"UnknownDowntime_Duration":0,"UnknownDowntime_Percent":0},{"ChartDate":null,"CycleStatus":null,"Cycle_Duration":0,"Cycle_Percent":0,"Duration":0,"EquipmentDescription":null,"EquipmentId":1,"EquipmentName":"PCS Loop 1","EquipmentStatusColor":null,"EquipmentStatusDescription":null,"EquipmentStatusId":0,"EquipmentStatusIdentifier":null,"EquipmentStatusTypeId":0,"EquipmentStatusTypeName":null,"EquipmentStatusTypeName_resourceKey":null,"EquipmentTimeZoneId":null,"EventData":null,"GeneralStatusState":0,"IsFirstRowData":false,"Percentage":0,"ReportGroupId":0,"ReportGroupName":null,"ReportGroupValue":null,"StatusAction":0,"StatusDuration":[{"ChartDate":null,"CycleStatus":null,"Cycle_Duration":0,"Cycle_Percent":0,"Duration":495.61333333332925,"EquipmentDescription":null,"EquipmentId":1,"EquipmentName":"PCS Loop 1","EquipmentStatusColor":"#008000","EquipmentStatusDescription":"In Cycle","EquipmentStatusId":0,"EquipmentStatusIdentifier":null,"EquipmentStatusTypeId":1,"EquipmentStatusTypeName":null,"EquipmentStatusTypeName_resourceKey":"EquipmentStatusTypeName.InCycle","EquipmentTimeZoneId":null,"EventData":null,"GeneralStatusState":0,"IsFirstRowData":false,"Percentage":0,"ReportGroupId":0,"ReportGroupName":null,"ReportGroupValue":null,"StatusAction":0,"StatusDuration":null,"TimeStamp":{"DateTime":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","OffsetMinutes":0},"UnknownDowntime_Duration":0,"UnknownDowntime_Percent":0},{"ChartDate":null,"CycleStatus":null,"Cycle_Duration":0,"Cycle_Percent":0,"Duration":200.56972222222623,"EquipmentDescription":null,"EquipmentId":1,"EquipmentName":"PCS Loop 1","EquipmentStatusColor":"#FFFF00","EquipmentStatusDescription":"In Cycle","EquipmentStatusId":0,"EquipmentStatusIdentifier":"","EquipmentStatusTypeId":2,"EquipmentStatusTypeName":null,"EquipmentStatusTypeName_resourceKey":"EquipmentStatusTypeNam
```

Now this is a response for five different equipments and how can i use this JSON string to an array so that i can extract the data of each equipment and send it to AChartEngine for drawing of chart?

Comment: your json-response is incomplete

Comment: yeah i noticed but i need to learn the concept. The response for 4 equipments is complete we can work on that. Rest i will manage and thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the response string to JSONObject. The response you posted is JSONArray.

```
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString);
     int size = jsonArray.length();
     ArrayList<JSONObject> arrayList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
     for(int i= 0; i< size; i++) {
          JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
          // use this jsonObject to get the value by passing the keys.
           String value = jsonObject.optString(key);

           //here is your array list of jsonobjects
           arrayList.add(jsonObject);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below Code for Pass JsonArray and store Value into ArrayList.

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(mRes);
ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i= 0; i< size; i++) {
    JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String mValue = jObject.getString("your_json_object_name");
    array1.add(mValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson api, it allows you to direct mapping of json objects to java objects. check following links for further reference:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide